# Are there any particular type of corn chips that are made from masa flour?

Tags: corn, tortilla-chips

I am wondering if the type "Mexican Style" or "Restauant Style"  or "Tortilla" corn chips also means they are made from masa flour? I cannot tell from the ingredients list. It does not say what process was used to make the corn flour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tortillas are made from masa.  So, if the chip is truly a "tortilla chip", then it was made with masa.  Corn chips, like the brand Fritos, are made from corn meal, I believe.  Masa is made from nixtamalized corn.  Corn meal or corn flour is simply ground corn.

Comment: @moscafj...I must confess I have an ulterior motive for wanting to know. I need lutein for my eyes and nih website says mesa flower may be high and since the ingredient list on "tortilla" chips does not say what process was used then I was at a loss. I will assume it was mesa flower. Your answer clears it up. Thank you